# How to match for more than one value in a string using regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, highlighting

Hi i want to highlight whole gold ring 
for this i am doing as

```
var match = hitem.text[0].match(/<em>(.*?)<\/em>/);
where hitem.text[0]=<em>Gold</em> <em>Ring</em>
```

but the problem is var match is getting only Gold so i am able to highlight only Gold, i want to make it an array so that it contains both gold and ring, how can i do it.
look at here http: http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "<em>Gold</em> <em>Ring</em>";
var rg = /<em>(.*?)<\/em>/g;

var res = new Array();

var match = rg.exec(s);
while(match != null){
    res.push(match[1])
    match = rg.exec(s);
}

alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the [global](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) modifier to your regexp, like this:

```
var match = hitem.text[0].match(/<em>(.*?)<\/em>/ig);
```

(I also added "i", which stands for "ignore case", I assume that's also necessary)

http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/19/

Comment: András Szepesházi: have u look at http://jsfiddle.net/bhXbh/19/ its not highlighting nything :(

Comment: András Szepesházi: When i am not using ig i got match as <em>Gold<em>,gold so i can use match[1] but after using ig i got match as <em>Gold</em>,<em>Ring</em> now how i got gold ring

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to iterate through all the matches using the regular expression objects `exec` method, and then save the first backref to an array. Note also the `/g` flag, which makes your regex global, that is, set up to capture all matches rather than just the first one:

```
var str = "<em>Gold</em> <em>Ring</em>";
var matches = [];
var re = /<em>(.*?)<\/em>/g;
while (match = re.exec(str)) { // Continues until no more matches are found
  matches.push(match[1]);      // Adds the first backreference
}
console.log(matches);          // returns ["Gold", "Ring"]
```

If you want to combine the `matches` into a string, of course, you could do `matches.join(" ");`.

**Other options**

If you don't mind capturing the surrounding `<em>` tags, you could do `var matches = str.match(re);`.

And if you just want to replace the `<em>` tags, you can do `str.replace(re, "$1");`.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework is contain a special class which you can use for your goal - MatchCollection class.

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{

    public static void Main ()
    {

        // Define a regular expression for repeated words.
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b",
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Define a test string.        
        string text = "The the quick brown fox  fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.";

        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        // Report the number of matches found.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}", 
                          matches.Count, 
                          text);

        // Report on each match.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at positions {1} and {2}",  
                              groups["word"].Value, 
                              groups[0].Index, 
                              groups[1].Index);
        }

    }

}
// The example produces the following output to the console:
//       3 matches found in:
//          The the quick brown fox  fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.
//       'The' repeated at positions 0 and 4
//       'fox' repeated at positions 20 and 25
//       'dog' repeated at positions 50 and 54
```